# add a parametr to layout with code

Tags: android

I went to add this code to activity that don't have any layout.
I went to add it with code

```
<ir.adad.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        token="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate the view, set the properties and then add it into activity/layout
e.g
private AdView mAdView;

Answer (score 0):

```
private AdView mAdView;
```

and do the following in your onCreate()

```
mAdView = new AdView(this);
```

Comment: how I can add it to current activity

Comment: You will have to get an handle to your current view. From the code you ahve shared i cant tell you much. you will have to share some more code.